Acts 11:21 translation
For what reasons lead to the different translation viewpoints?
Why are there so many differing ways of translating this passage even among the literal translations?
ESV/NASB/LSB/(CSB/HCSB) "And the hand of the Lord was with them, and a large number who believed turned to the Lord."
What is the justification for adding the 'who' in this translation?
vs.
KJV/NKJV "And the hand of the Lord was with them, and a great number believed and turned to the Lord."
What is the justification for add 'and' before 'turned'?
vs.
LSV/Young's "and the hand of the LORD was with them, a great number also, having believed, turned to the LORD."
What's the justification for adding the word 'having'?
Whose justification for their adding words into their translation is superior and fits the natural way the greek is read?

Englishman's Greek New Testament (Interlinear, Literal) from Stephanus 1550 : And was hand of Lord with them and a great number having believed turned to the Lord 'having' is added to convey the aorist participle active into an English past continuous. We don't need 'a' the English indefinite article : it would be better to dispense with it as neither Hebrew nor Greek possess such a concept.

Why are there so many differing ways of translating this passage even among the literal translations?
Let's cover this first question.
All faithful translations try to achieve a balance of four elements: [1]

Accuracy to the original text as much as possible.
Beauty of language.
Clarity of meaning.
Dignity of style.


However, take for example a phrase in French: “C’est la vie,” which literally translates to ‘This is the life’. This phrase can be translated into English in many ways, each carrying a slightly different nuance:

“That’s life.”
“Such is life.”
“Life goes on.”
“It is what it is.”

Each of these translations captures the essence of acceptance or resignation that is implied by the original French phrase. However, they do so with different connotations:
“That’s life” is a common expression that implies a shrug and acceptance of reality.
“Such is life” has a slightly more philosophical tone like a reflection on the nature of life.
“Life goes on” is about the continuity of life despite challenges.
“It is what it is” conveys a modern, acceptance of the situation.

Without adding any words and using the original structure and word order, it would result in a translation that looks something like... Here’s what it would look like:

“And was the hand of the Lord with them, a great number then, having
believed, turned to the Lord.”

Yeah. It sounds somewhat awkward in English.

Now, regarding the specific translations you mentioned:
ESV/NASB/LSB/(CSB/HCSB): Note that the addition of ‘who’ helps clarify to the reader that it’s not just any large number, but specifically those who believed. So, there is faith before the action of turning.
KJV/NKJV: ‘and’ maintains the structure of the original Greek, which often uses conjunctions to link clauses. It does two things: It can imply a sequence—first belief, then turning. Or it can imply a logical conjunction where they did both—believed and turned.
LSV/Young’s: ‘Having’ indicates that belief was a precondition to turning to the Lord. It shows the process.
My conclusion after looking at each translation: No translation is superior.

ESV/NASB/LSB/(CSB/HCSB)  What is the justification for adding the 'who' in this translation?
Translating an articular participle as "who [action expressed by the lexeme]" is a quite
straight-forward, elementary Greek, suggested translation.  And I don't mean to disparage it.  It's
Greek 101.  So, it's a clean lexical translation.  Though lexical translations often present
comprehension problems when placed into larger discourse sized, English texts.  This happens because
such translations introduce meaning that isn't in the original and leave out meaning that is there.
Other elements in the discourse can't correct the ambiguity.  It's lexically based, after all.  So,
it can't take advantage of the English idiomatic patterning to convey the original meaning.
This is a good translation.
KJV/NKJV  What is the justification for add 'and' before 'turned'?
The problem the translators are trying to solve is the fact that the two words, πολύς and ἀριθμὸς,
translated as 'a great number', are in the nominative case and so is the articular participle
just mentioned above.  So, you have a nominative phrase, πολύς τε ἀριθμὸς, in apposition to a
nominative articular participle.  So, they work together.  But, that's complicated by the fact that a participle is a
verbal adjective.  So, there's a verbal idea resident in the word.  So, the subject of the
sentence is modified by a verbal idea which in turn needs to be connected to the actual verb.  The
question is how to bring that verbal idea that is modifying the subject over into English.  So, what
the translators did was they expressed the verbal idea of the participle more strongly and connected
it with the actual verb using 'and'.
Another possible problem the translators were solving was a fairly straight-forward lexical
translation is "...the believers turned...".  Obviously, that doesn't convey the meaning since
English is more tuned to tense (the time factor of a verb) than it is the aspect of the verb (simple
belief).  So, that English rendering sounds like the people first were believers and then later
turned.  That's not the Greek meaning.  So, a straight-forward, literal rendering conveys wrong
meaning.
Also, Greek aorist participles are not past participles because they are aorist.  An aorist
states the fact of the action (simple belief).  Participles will get their sense of time relative
to the main verb.  Here, both participle and main verb are aorist, so they'll very likely occur at
the same time.  The translators solved the contemporaneous meaning by using the word 'and'.
The problem I have with this translation is that the participle is articular.  So, it strongly tends
to make the participle adjectival (or even substantival, 'the believers').  It might be that 400 year
old English didn't comprehend this translation in the way I've described.  I'm analyzing it from the
modern English perspective.  In any case, the participle is not a verb in parallel to the main verb.
This is an OK translation.  A person simply reading it won't trip over the inaccuracy and it does
capture quite well the fact that the believing and the turning occur at the same time.
LSV/Young's  What's the justification for adding the word 'having'?
One way to interpret the use of a participle is as an adverbial clause.  So, the way to bring a
Greek adverbial participle over into English is to simply tack an '-ing' to the end of it.  We would
have, "a great number of people believing".  That's not quite correct since the participle is an
aorist, which would be more literally rendered as 'believed'.  However, if it's rendered that way,
it sounds like a main verb and is therefore not adverbial.  One way to finesse that is to render as
"having believed".
The problem with all of that is the participle is articular.  While it's not a hard and fast rule
that, "if it's articular, it's a substantive", an adverbial participle here would be much more
naturally anarthrous.  Also, it's an odd word order for an adverbial participle.  I would have
thought it would be first in the sentence, followed by the subject (πολύς τε ἀριθμὸς) and then the
main verb.
I think this translation is incorrect.
Whose justification for their adding words into their translation is superior and fits the natural
way the Greek is read?
I think one of the difficulties translators have with this Greek text is Luke is conveying some
excitement.  He uses the expression, πολύς τε ἀριθμὸς.  The words, πολύς and ἀριθμὸς are redundant.
And the word, τε, signals a very close connection between the words it connects.  Sometimes it
should be translated as, "and also".  So, why the redundancy and why the emphasis on joining the two
concepts (it's not just 'and')?  I think that's excitement.  Things are taking off, and Gentiles
are exploding onto the scene.  So, I would render the phrase, πολύς τε ἀριθμὸς, as "many even
numerous".  This excitement also explains why Luke immediately follows up with an articular
nominative participle, further defining who these many people are.  The excitement is  clearer if
you hear the text instead of read it.
The phrase, χεὶρ κυρίου, ("hand of Lord"), probably means something closer to an English, "the
Lord's personal involvement".  That's not to imply that there's any case when the Lord is not
personally involved any more than "the hand of the Lord" means that there are times when the Lord
needs his hand to do something or that there's times when he does something without using his hand
(whatever that could mean).  However, the expression does, again, speak to the excitement that Luke
conveys in this text.  The Lord is moving!
Given the fact that the participle modifies the subject, 'many even numerous', and the
participle is aligned in time with the main verb, I'd suggest a translation of:

"The Lord was personally engaged:  many, even numerous, now believers,
turned to the Lord!"

Read that out loud, with appropriate pauses, and see what you think.

Here is my overly literal translation of Acts 11:21 -

And hand of Lord was with them; then great number the having believed
turned to the Lord.

Notice that there is no "the" before "hand" and no "the" before the first "Lord".  However, there is a "the" before "having believed".  Now, in the original Greek this makes perfect sense and is good grammar.
However, when translating to another language, adjustments must be made in the receiving language to make grammatical sense.  Some "the"s must be added and deleted as required.  The same is true of "and"s.  Thus, a good grammatical translation of the above would need to look something like this:

The hand of the Lord was with them and, a great number who
believed turned to the Lord.


Notice that I have also had to add an "a" as well.
the verb πιστεύσας is an aorist participle active and thus must be translated, not "believed" but "having believed.  The alternative would need to be "who believed" to make English sense.


The differences seen among the various translations of Acts 11:21 are related to how the aorist participle of the verb pisteuō (πιστεύω Strong’s G4100 meaning to believe, entrust) is rendered. The participle is a verbal adjective and is difficult to translate because it can function as either an adjective, noun, adverb, or verb.
Greek Participles

A participle is called a 'verbal adjective' because it is formed from
a verb, yet often modifies other words. Oftentimes it may be hard to
translate a participle into English and still bring out the same force
as it has in the Greek. First try to understand the meaning of the
Greek participle is trying to convey, then worry about an appropriate
English translation. The translation may have to be as an English
relative clause when used adjectivally in Greek.

One way to categorize a participle is according to emphasis, whether adjectival or verbal. In this regard the first thing to ask is whether a particular participle has an article. While the article is generally not translated into English, its presence says that the participle is adjectival. According to Wallace, if an article “stands before a participle and functions as a modifying article (normal use), then that participle must be adjectival” (The Basics of New Testament Syntax, p. 271). When a participle is anarthrous, it could be adjectival or it could function in some other way.
There is a textual variant in Acts 11:21 wherein some Greek texts have the article before the participle πιστεύσας and others do not. Notably, the Textus Receptus, the basis of the KJV and YLT, does not have the article before πιστεύσας.
MGNT
πολύς       τε      ἀριθμὸς    ὁ    πιστεύσας           ἐπέστρεψεν
[a] great   then    number     -    having believed     turned

Textus Receptus
πολύς   τε      ἀριθμὸς     πιστεύσας           ἐπέστρεψεν
great   then    number      having believed     turned

The KJV translates the participle πιστεύσας as a verb and connects it to the main verb with the conjunction “and.” Wallace calls this the Attendant Circumstance participle and defines it as one that is “used to communicate an action that, in some sense, is coordinate with the finite verb” (The Basics of New Testament Syntax, p. 281).

and a great number believed, and turned unto the Lord – KJV

Young’s Literal Translation, on the other hand, translates πιστεύσας as “having believed,” an English perfect participle (“having” plus a past participle). In keeping with the aorist tense of the participle, YLT's rendering implies that the action of the participle (believed) precedes that of the main verb (turned).

a great number also, having believed, did turn unto the Lord – YLT

The last group of translations, which includes the ESV, renders πιστεύσας as “who believed,” a relative clause that modifies “a great number,” the subject of the main verb. As noted in the reference above, using a relative clause to translate an adjectival participle is fairly standard practice.

And the hand of the Lord was with them, and a great number who
believed turned to the Lord – ESV

The OP asks which translation is superior. The KJV translates the participle as a verb in order to stress the coordination between the action of the participle and that of the main verb. YLT uses the perfect participle to stress the timing/sequence of the two actions. Rather than focusing on the action/verbal aspect of the participle, translations that render the participle with the relative clause emphasize its adjectival function.
In context, the passage describes a conflict that arose from the unexpected and somewhat problematic identity of the Gentile converts. Given this context, I prefer translations that render πιστεύσας with a relative clause because less emphasis falls on what the converts do and more on who they are - those “who believed.” Indeed, the theme of the passage is not the actions of men, but the grace of God and the work of the Holy Spirit in sowing the seeds of faith.
Acts 11:32 ESV

And the hand of the Lord was with them, and a great number who
believed turned to the Lord.

